# Why do I get an error when I add to Arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
``public class Data {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    Data(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
    
...more bunch of codes...
    
    
}

public class Lab5 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Data x = new Data("Fred", 41);
        x.Print();
    }

    public static void PrintCollection(Collection<Data> c) {
        for (Iterator<Data> iter = c.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Data x = (Data) iter.next();
            x.Print();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    ArrayList<Data> array = new ArrayList<Data>();
    
    array.add("Jack",42);  //error , why?
    array.add("Marie",22);//error
    array.add("David", 41); //error

}
`
`
```

I am supposed to add these 3 items to the arrayList but I keep getting error, I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I tried putting ArrayList into the main method it but it doesnt work like that as well. I was expecting these three items to be added and printed.

Answer (score 3):

You have an `ArrayList<Data>`, thus the `add` method takes one parameter of type `Data`. Calling `array.add("Jack", 42)` is not possible because you pass a `String` and an `Integer` as parameters. A method like that doesn't exist in `ArrayList` and also makes no sense.

You need to create instances of your `Data` class and add these to the `List`:

```
array.add(new Data("Jack",42));
```